# on one PC with same IE8 version and same OS loads corectly web page on other get strange problem!

Tags: jquery, flash, internet-explorer-8, swfobject

Can any one help to solve the problem with IE8 on my computer http://www.lifestyletelevision.tv/lstv2/ flash player loads us it should be, but on other computer same version IE8 on refreshing the same page flash player screen stays in same possition but content moves to the let possition...

Comment: Is this a PC question, or a web design question (i.e. it's your site you're building)? The former would belong on Superuser.com

Comment: Is the display resolution same on both PCs?

Comment: To Pekka: Yes it is web desing question.

Comment: To Salman A: I dont think it is display resolution problem, becouse it first time it loads corectly, just on refresh it's moves to bad possition. I thought it is jquery and swfobject problem but I downloaded IE8 on my computer and it still works, but not in other pc with IE8

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx

the compatibility view COULD cause some differences in the viewing.
it might be that one of the two IE8 browsers is in that mode.